# Iterating through values to find average equation of a line (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics

I am trying to find the equation of a line within a DF

Here is a fake data set to explain:

```
 Clicks       Sales
   5            10
   5            11
   10           16
   10           20
   10           18
   15           28
   15           26
   ...          ...
   100          200
```

**What I am trying to do:**

Calculate the equation of the line between so that I am able to input a number of clicks and have an output of sales at any predicted level.  **The thing I am trying to wrap my brain around** is that I have many different line functions (e.g. there are multiple sales for each amount of clicks).  How can I iterate through my DF to just to calculate one aggregate line function?

Here's what I have but it only accept ONE input at a time, I would like to create an average or aggregate...

```
  def slope(self, target):
        return slope(target.x - self.x, target.y - self.y)

  def y_int(self, target):       # <= here's the magic
      return self.y - self.slope(target)*self.x

  def line_function(self, target):
        slope = self.slope(target)
        y_int = self.y_int(target)
        def fn(x):
            return slope*x + y_int
        return fn

a = Point(5, 10) # I am stuck here since - what to input!?  
b = Point(10, 16) # I am stuck here since - what to input!?
line = a.line_function(b)
print(line(x=10))
```

Comment: I apologize if I am misunderstanding your question, but it sounds like you have a lot of data with a bunch of predictors (clicks) and responses (sales) You are hoping to find the relationship between these two sets of data? Have you plotted your data? does fitting a line to it even make sense? If so what should that line look like? Is it straight, curved, polynomial? The simplest solution for you is likely [linear regression](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/regression.html). But of course this has caveats. [Anscombes quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scipy` function [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) to fit your data.
Maybe also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression to better understand linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by `Clicks` and take the average of the `Sales` per group:

```
In [307]: sales = df.groupby('Clicks')['Sales'].mean(); sales
Out[307]: 
Clicks
5       10.5
10      18.0
15      27.0
100    200.0
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Then form the **piecewise linear interpolating function** based on
the groupwise-averaged data above using [`interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
from scipy import interpolate
fn = interpolate.interp1d(sales.index, sales.values, kind='linear')
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Clicks': [5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 100],
                   'Sales': [10, 11, 16, 20, 18, 28, 26, 200]})

sales = df.groupby('Clicks')['Sales'].mean()
```

Once you have the groupwise-averaged `sales`, you can compute the interpolated sales
a number of ways. One way is to use [`np.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
newx = [10]
print(np.interp(newx, sales.index, sales.values))
# [ 18.]   <-- The interpolated sales when the number of clicks is 10 (newx)
```

The problem with `np.interp` is that you are passing `sales.index` and `sales.values` to `np.interp` every time you call it -- it has no memory of the interpolating function. It is re-computing the interpolating function every time you call it.

If you have scipy, then you could create the interpolating function *once* and then use it as many times as you like later:

```
fn = interpolate.interp1d(sales.index, sales.values, kind='linear')
print(fn(newx))
# [ 18.]
```

For example, you could evaluate the interpolating function at a whole bunch of points (and plot the result) like this:

```
newx = np.linspace(5, 100, 100)
plt.plot(newx, fn(newx))
plt.plot(df['Clicks'], df['Sales'], 'o')
plt.show()
```

### [image]

Pandas Series (and DataFrames) have an [`iterpolate` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) too. To use it, you reindex the Series to include the points where you wish to interpolate:

```
In [308]: sales.reindex(sales.index.union([14]))
Out[308]: 
5       10.5
10      18.0
14       NaN
15      27.0
100    200.0
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

and then `interpolate` fills in the interpolated values where the Series is NaN:

```
In [295]: sales.reindex(sales.index.union([14])).interpolate('values')
Out[295]: 
5       10.5
10      18.0
14      25.2   # <-- interpolated value
15      27.0
100    200.0
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

But I think it is perhaps not appropriate for your problem since it does not
return just the interpolated values you are looking for; it returns a whole
Series.